# Why do I get 0xc0000098 while booting Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

On a HP pavilion G series with Windows 7 home basic model I get the following error:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc0000098
```

I have tried to insert recovery CD's and tried to repair with the Windows 7 CD, the boot error remains.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **err** utility, searching for that code yields:

```
# for hex 0xc0000098 / decimal -1073741672 :
  STATUS_FILE_INVALID                                           ntstatus.h
# The volume for a file has been externally altered such that
# the opened file is no longer valid.
```

IOTW; due to corruption, the Windows Boot Configuration Data file does not contain a valid OS entry.

You will want to [**rebuild the BCD**](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm); in short, you can do it like this:

1. Boot from the Windows 7 CD.
2. Open a command prompt (either press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> or select it in the repair tools).
3. Run the following commands:

   ```
   bcdedit /export C:\bcd.backup
   attrib C:\boot\bcd -h -r -s
   ren C:\boot\bcd C:\bcd.old
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```
4. When asked for adding your installation to the list, hit **Y**.
5. Restart and enjoy.

Comment: `ren C:\boot\bcd C:\bcd.old` complained about bad syntax. The only way I could make it work was to cd into the directory and refer to it with a relative path, i.e. `BCD`