# Windows BCD error after installing Linux distro

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, bcd, easybcd

I installed a Linux distro alongside Windows, however for some reason the GRUB menu didn't appear and not set up properly so I repartitioned the Linux drive in Windows and used EasyBCD to try and fix the MBR and what not.

However in the process, I must have messed up the Windows UEFI settings and ended up fixing the GRUB using the Boot-Repair tool in a Ubuntu live CD.

Now I can see both Windows and Linux in GRUB, but I can't boot into Windows and keep getting this error message:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc0000098

  Info: The Windows Base Configuration Data file does not contain a valid
        OS entry.
```

I tried using bootrec in a Windows recovery cmd live USB, but kept getting `access denied`.

I was wondering if there are any tools that can fix it? I can boot into my Debian perfectly fine, is there a way to fix it in there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get 0xc0000098 while booting Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/869180/why-do-i-get-0xc0000098-while-booting-windows-7)

Comment: are we in the same boat? https://superuser.com/q/1624073/591831