# Windows doesn't update after installing Linux as dual boot

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, fat32, fixmbr

I have a windows 10 I installed linux (ubuntu) and boots with grub, I believe the reason windows doesn't update is because it doesn't boot using windows bootloader so it reverts the attempted updates
I attempted to make windows the bootlaoder with easyBCD but my PC wouldnt boot after I did that, so I booted into linux live bootable usb and ran boot repair so I'm back to grub, now the question is whats the next step, I read this post https://askubuntu.com/a/497690/821246 but I have a few questions

1. List vol returns, can it be NTFS or it must be fat32

   ```
   DISKPART> list vol

     Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
     ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
     Volume 0     F                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
     Volume 1     E                NTFS   Partition    200 MB  Healthy
     Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition    254 GB  Healthy    System
     Volume 3     D   LENOVO       NTFS   Partition     28 GB  Healthy
   ```

2. C:drive is marked as system, doesn't the boot sector need to be system which in my case its drive E:
3. boot sector has E: assigned is that ok? or it needs to be removed
4. when i booted from USB bootrec /fixboot returned access denied does that mean that my boot (something is corrupt or I need to use a  different command (I saw some talk that you need to use bootsect)